indent: how can I avoid that indent makes/takes back an adjustment each run?
I am using indent to format code in a c project of mine: https://github.com/eantoranz/gitmod/ (v0.11)
If you take code and run make format, it will apply a change (using linux format):
$ git diff
$ make format
indent -l120 -linux src/gitmod/*.c src/include/*.h src/include/gitmod/*.h src/tests/unit_tests/*.c src/tests/unit_tests/*.h
find ./ -name '*~' -delete
$ git diff
diff --git a/src/gitmod/thread.c b/src/gitmod/thread.c
index 8211b61..1ef7d1d 100644
--- a/src/gitmod/thread.c
+++ b/src/gitmod/thread.c
@@ -19,7 +19,7 @@ static void *thread_task(void *params)
 
 gitmod_thread *gitmod_thread_create(gitmod_info *info, void (*task)(gitmod_thread *), int delay)
 {
-       if (!info)
+       if(!info)
                return NULL;
        gitmod_thread *thread = calloc(1, sizeof(gitmod_thread));
        if (thread) {

But you run it again, and the change is taken back.:
$ make format
indent -l120 -linux src/gitmod/*.c src/include/*.h src/include/gitmod/*.h src/tests/unit_tests/*.c src/tests/unit_tests/*.h
find ./ -name '*~' -delete
$ git diff
$

Line of code with the problem: https://www.github.com/eantoranz/gitmod/blob/v0.11/src/gitmod/thread.c#L22
Makefile target:
format:
    indent -l120 -linux src/gitmod/*.c src/include/*.h src/include/gitmod/*.h src/tests/unit_tests/*.c src/tests/unit_tests/*.h
    find ./ -name '*~' -delete

It can be seen over here: https://github.com/eantoranz/gitmod/blob/v0.11/Makefile#L49
What can I do in the indent call to avoid this problem?
Side note: What tools do you use for the same task?

To answer your side note: clang-format is a good C formatter.

Please at least show what your format target looks like

What's in your indent config file?  Or what's implied by the -linux style option?  It's interesting that it is if (!info) that has the problem whereas if (thread) does not.  The exclamation mark is probably a part of the issue, therefore, though it might be related to the presence or absence of the open brace on the same line as if statement.  It's hard to say without a bit more code.

Did you perhaps git add + commit after the first run? If so, the second run will not change the files. I wasn't able to reproduce your issue by just running the indent command twice anyway.

That was straight, no commit in the middle.

@TedLyngmo Is the format target the first arguments in the indentcall (indent -l120 -linux)? If it is so, it can be seen as the first line of output when calling make format.

@eftshift0 I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. I would like to see the definition of your format target (and any other targets it depends on and make macros used).

Oh, I C... you mean, in Makefile? Will add it in the question

find ./ -name '*~' -delete it's odd to remove files on formatting. Instead, consider adding *~ to .gitignore. Vim swap files have a purpouse. If you do not like vim temporary files, configure vim.

That's a good point, thanks for bringing it up.
